How to add animation when removing an item in HorizontalPager in Jetpack Compose
I have an HorizontalPager in Compose and users are able to remove any item of Pager. When the user removes any item i want other elements move to empty place with an animation.
This is actually a default animation for RecylerView(ListAdapter) or even LazyColumn uses animateItem to manage that or with deprecated name animateItemPlacement.
I'm wondering how can I achieve the same concept in HorizontalPager?
@Composable
fun HomePageBanner(
    bannerList: List<BannerUIModel>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onButtonClicked: (index: Int) -> Unit = {},
    onItemRemoved: (index: Int) -> Unit = {},
) {
    val pageCount = bannerList.size
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = { pageCount })
    HorizontalPager(
        state = pagerState,
        modifier = modifier,
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(start = 16.dp, end = 12.dp),
        pageSpacing = 0.dp,
    ) { index ->
        val banner = bannerList[index]
        BannerCardItem(
            bannerItem = banner,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(12.dp),
            onButtonClicked = { onButtonClicked(index) },
            onItemRemoved = {
                // When this is called, the item will be removed 
                // and HomePageBanner will be called with the new list
                onItemRemoved(index)
            },
        )
    }
}


Please [edit] your question and provide the code you have so far.

Actually this question is independent of code because I am looking for the equivalent of the default animation used in Lists in the Android world for Compose Pager. I'll still share the basic implementation of the Pager.

Modifier.animateItem() is a scoped Modifier defined in LazyItemScope. There is no default PagerScope modifier, actually nothing in PagerScope yet. You can open a feature request for Pager as well.
/**
 * Receiver scope for [Pager].
 * Note: This is empty now, but we may add new members in the future if needed.
 */
sealed interface PagerScope

internal object PagerScopeImpl : PagerScope

But You can apply snapping behavior to LazyRow/Column you can snap as Pager does and use Modifer.animateItem()
Animating LazyRow item change

Data class must have unique keys for matching which items to animate for placement, which ones for appear and which ones for disappear and must be used inside key = {item-> item.id}.
data class MyData(val id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(), val value: Int)

class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val list =
        mutableStateListOf<MyData>().apply {
            repeat(6) {
                add(
                    MyData(value = it)
                )
            }
        }

    fun removeItem(index: Int) {
        list.removeAt(index)
    }
}


@Preview
@Composable
fun LazyRowSnapAndDeleteAnimation() {

    val viewModel = remember {
        MyViewModel()
    }

    val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(backgroundColor).padding(vertical = 32.dp)
    ) {

        val list = viewModel.list

        LazyRow(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(start = 16.dp, end = 12.dp),
            flingBehavior = rememberSnapFlingBehavior(lazyListState, snapPosition = SnapPosition.Start),
            state = lazyListState
        ) {

            itemsIndexed(
                items = list,
                key = { _, item ->
                    item.id
                }
            ) { page, item ->
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .animateItem()
                        .fillParentMaxWidth()
                        .height(200.dp)
                        .shadow(2.dp, RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
                        .background(Color.White)
                        .padding(32.dp)
                ) {
                    Text("Item")

                    Button(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        onClick = {
                            viewModel.removeItem(page)
                        }
                    ) {
                        Text("Remove ${item.value}")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Animating HorizontalPager item change

If using LazyRow is out of question you can write a Modifier that does that but it's not easy and there are several cases to handle since we are building similar Modifier as animateItem manually.
Basically, you need to set Modifier.layout with layer, also HorizontalPager has fixed page size, do not let items shrink you need to handle item scrolling. In addition, in your case, you should also handle cases for previous and next items because of content padding makes them partially visible.
Step1 - Using a flag to signal animation
When manually animating deleted items first step is using a flag to make them eligible for animation then after animation finishes because removin items list removes them from composition, so they must be removed at the end.
Or you can use another list to compare as LazyList does to check which items to change position, which items to disappear and which ones to appear.
Updated ViewModel and data like this
data class MyData(val id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(), val value: Int, val isAlive: Boolean = true)

class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val list =
        mutableStateListOf<MyData>().apply {
            repeat(6) {
                add(
                    MyData(value = it)
                )
            }
        }

    fun updateStatus(index: Int) {
        val newItem = list[index].copy(isAlive = false)
        list[index] = newItem
        println("Update Status: $index")
    }

    fun removeItem(index: Int) {
        println(" Remove item: $index")
        list.removeAt(index)
    }
}

Step2 - Creating a modifier to animate items
In this step using an Animatable to track progress and with Modifier.layout to change scale, alpha, etc, depending on preference but you must invoke scroll because Pagers have fixed page sizes.
fun  Modifier.animatePagerItem(
animate: Boolean,
page: Int,
list: List,
pagerState: PagerState,
onStart: (page: Int) -> Unit,
onFinish: (page: Int) -> Unit,
) = composed {
val animatable = remember {
    Animatable(1f)
}

LaunchedEffect(animate) {
    if (animate) {
        val animationSpec = tween<Float>(1000)

        onStart(page)
        launch {
            try {
                animatable.animateTo(
                    targetValue = 0f,
                    animationSpec = animationSpec,
                )
                onFinish(page)
            } catch (e: CancellationException) {
                println("CANCELED $page, ${e.message}")
                onFinish(page)
            }
        }

        if (list.size > 1 && page != list.lastIndex) {
            launch {
                pagerState.animateScrollToPage(
                    page = page + 1,
                    animationSpec = animationSpec
                )
            }
        } else if (page == list.lastIndex) {
            pagerState.animateScrollToPage(
                page = page - 1,
                animationSpec = animationSpec
            )
        }
    }
}

Modifier.layout { measurable, constraints ->
    val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)

    val difference = -constraints.maxWidth * (1 - animatable.value)

    layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
        placeable.placeRelativeWithLayer(0, 0) {

            transformOrigin = TransformOrigin(0f, .5f)
            translationX = if (list.size > 1 && page != list.lastIndex) {
                -difference
            } else if (list.size > 1 && page == list.lastIndex) {
                difference
            } else 0f

            translationY = -300f * (1 - animatable.value)
            alpha = animatable.value

            // Other animations

//                scaleY = (animatable.value).coerceAtLeast(.8f)
cameraDistance = (1 - animatable.value) * 100
//                rotationY = -30f * (1 - animatable.value)
//                scaleX = animatable.value
        }
    }
}

}
I didn't cover only having one item, removing item at the end and animating previous and next items if they are partially visible when content padding is used or width smaller than HorizontalPager width. Need to set scroll position to page - 1 when last item is removed and getting partially visible item indices to set offsetX for them as well if needed.
Usage
@Preview
@Composable
fun PagerRemoveAnimationSample() {

    val viewModel = remember {
        MyViewModel()
    }

    val list = viewModel.list

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(backgroundColor)
//            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {

        val pagerState = rememberPagerState {
            list.size
        }

        var userGestureEnabled by remember {
            mutableStateOf(true)
        }

        HorizontalPager(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(200.dp),
            state = pagerState,
            pageSpacing = 16.dp,
//            contentPadding = PaddingValues(start = 16.dp, end = 12.dp),
            userScrollEnabled = userGestureEnabled,
            key = {
                list[it].id
            }
        ) { page: Int ->
            list.getOrNull(page)?.let { item ->

                val animate = item.isAlive.not()

                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(200.dp)
                        .animatePagerItem(
                            animate = animate,
                            page = page,
                            list = list,
                            pagerState = pagerState,
                            onStart = {
                                userGestureEnabled = false
                            },
                            onFinish = {
                                userGestureEnabled = true
                                viewModel.removeItem(it)
                            }
                        )
                        .shadow(2.dp, RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
                        .background(Color.White)
                        .padding(32.dp)
                ) {
                    Text(
                        "value: ${item.value}\n" +
                                "isScrollInProgress: ${pagerState.isScrollInProgress}\n" +
                                "fraction: ${pagerState.currentPageOffsetFraction}\n" +
                                "currentPage: ${pagerState.currentPage}\n" +
                                "settledPage: ${pagerState.settledPage}"
                    )

                    Button(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        onClick = {
                            if (userGestureEnabled) {
                                viewModel.updateStatus(page)
                            }
                        }
                    ) {
                        Text("Remove ${item.value}")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Edit

Covered deleting last item and only when there is one item. Only missing thing if you are showing partially visible items on each side to handle their offset while scroll pushes them left or right. Also changed animation type different than first for demonstration.
fun <T> Modifier.animatePagerItem(
    animate: Boolean,
    page: Int,
    list: List<T>,
    pagerState: PagerState,
    onStart: (page: Int) -> Unit,
    onFinish: (page: Int) -> Unit,
) = composed {

    val animatable = remember {
        Animatable(1f)
    }

    LaunchedEffect(animate) {
        if (animate) {
            val animationSpec = tween<Float>(1000)

            onStart(page)
            launch {
                try {
                    animatable.animateTo(
                        targetValue = 0f,
                        animationSpec = animationSpec,
                    )
                    onFinish(page)
                } catch (e: CancellationException) {
                    println("CANCELED $page, ${e.message}")
                    onFinish(page)
                }
            }

            if (list.size > 1 && page != list.lastIndex) {
                launch {
                    pagerState.animateScrollToPage(
                        page = page + 1,
                        animationSpec = animationSpec
                    )
                }
            } else if (page == list.lastIndex) {
                pagerState.animateScrollToPage(
                    page = page - 1,
                    animationSpec = animationSpec
                )
            }
        }
    }

    Modifier.layout { measurable, constraints ->
        val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)

        val difference = -constraints.maxWidth * (1 - animatable.value)

        layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
            placeable.placeRelativeWithLayer(0, 0) {

                transformOrigin = TransformOrigin(0f, .5f)
                translationX = if (list.size > 1 && page != list.lastIndex) {
                    -difference
                } else if (list.size > 1 && page == list.lastIndex) {
                    difference
                } else 0f

                translationY = -300f * (1 - animatable.value)
                alpha = animatable.value

                // Other animations
//                scaleY = (animatable.value).coerceAtLeast(.8f)
                cameraDistance = (1 - animatable.value) * 100
//                rotationY = -30f * (1 - animatable.value)
//                scaleX = animatable.value

            }
        }
    }

}

By the way you can also reduce fling velocity to have similar behavior as Pager. I posted an example here.

Checking Modifier.animateItem delete animations again it only animates alpha. So you can remove other animations in layer and set scroll position for animating last item and for handling partially visible items you can send page and index to animate to translateX if for previous and next items. I might add this tomorrow if i'm available.

I don't know how to thank you. This was just what I needed and I'm completely achieved it with LazyRow you shared. Also thank you for reducing fling velocity trick. Now I have completely an HorizontalPager with animation.

Oh, now I saw that. I was always big fan of your content in LinkedIn. Maybe someone in the future might want to use the second option. For now, I'm not forced to use HorizontalPager. It was a great idea to getting benefit from LazyRow's animation.

Thanks. Also in second option, it's important if you are building delete animations manually use a flag to make an item eligible for animation first for it to be in composition until animation ends. After animation ends remove item from the list.
